Configuring a Cisco switch VLAN for WiFi guests
I have a Cisco Catalyst 2970 switch with a Firewalla firewall on switch port 13 and Linksys MX4000 V2 WiFi running OpenWRT on switch ports 3 and 5.
I would like my Cisco to provide trunks to these to ports for VLANs 1 (default) and 99 (guest).
If I connect my WiFi directly to my firewall, traffic from my guest SSID is correctly given the VLAN99 IP address and firewall rules. But when I go through my Cisco, all clients, regardless of SSID, receive the default network address and firewall rules.
What do I need to change in my switch configuration to get the desired behavior?
Switch#show int Gi0/3 trunk

Port Mode Encapsulation Status Native vlan
Gi0/3 on 802.1q trunking 1

Port Vlans allowed on trunk
Gi0/3 1-4094

Port Vlans allowed and active in management domain
Gi0/3 1,99

Port Vlans in spanning tree forwarding state and not pruned
Gi0/3 1,99

Switch#show int trunk

Port Mode Encapsulation Status Native vlan
Gi0/3 on 802.1q trunking 1
Gi0/5 on 802.1q trunking 1
Gi0/13 on 802.1q trunking 1

Port Vlans allowed on trunk
Gi0/3 1-4094
Gi0/5 1-4094
Gi0/13 1-4094

Port Vlans allowed and active in management domain
Gi0/3 1,99
Gi0/5 1,99
Gi0/13 1,99

Port Vlans in spanning tree forwarding state and not pruned
Gi0/3 1,99
Gi0/5 1,99
Gi0/13 1,99

Switch#show int vlan99
Vlan99 is up, line protocol is up
Hardware is EtherSVI, address is 0015.fa04.b441 (bia 0015.fa04.b441)
MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit, DLY 10 usec,
reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
Last input 00:00:03, output never, output hang never
Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
Queueing strategy: fifo
Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
56128 packets input, 18114955 bytes, 0 no buffer
Received 0 broadcasts (0 IP multicast)
0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
0 packets output, 0 bytes, 0 underruns
0 output errors, 0 interface resets
0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out

Switch#show int vlan1
Vlan1 is up, line protocol is up
Hardware is EtherSVI, address is 0015.fa04.b440 (bia 0015.fa04.b440)
Internet address is 192.168.173.254/24
MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit, DLY 10 usec,
reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
Last input 00:00:00, output 00:00:00, output hang never
Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
Queueing strategy: fifo
Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
432366 packets input, 52744175 bytes, 0 no buffer
Received 0 broadcasts (0 IP multicast)
0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
35452 packets output, 2358921 bytes, 0 underruns
0 output errors, 0 interface resets
0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out


EDIT 1 add output of show running-config
Switch#show running-config
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1934 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug uptime
service timestamps log uptime
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
enable secret 5 REDACTED
!
no aaa new-model
ip subnet-zero
!
!
!
!
no file verify auto
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
interface Port-channel3
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security
 switchport port-security aging time 2
 switchport port-security violation restrict
 switchport port-security aging type inactivity
 macro description cisco-desktop
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/5
 switchport access vlan 99
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/6
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/7
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/8
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/9
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/10
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/11
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/12
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/13
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/14
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/15
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/16
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/17
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/18
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/19
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/20
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/21
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/22
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/23
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/24
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 192.168.173.254 255.255.255.0
 no ip route-cache
!
interface Vlan99
 no ip address
 no ip route-cache
!
ip default-gateway 192.168.173.1
ip http server
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
line vty 0 4
 password REDACTED
 login
line vty 5 15
 password REDACTED
 login
!
!
end


Are your firewall and wifi also tagging vlans?  If not, you need to make them access ports.

VLAN tagging must match on both sides of the link. You should double check the settings there, but we cannot help you with consumer-grade devices -  for a device to be on topic here the vendor needs to offer optional, paid support, see the [help/on-topic].

yes both end devices are tagging vlan.

my request is for help configuring the cisco not the end devices. as I said, if I connect the devices directly and bypass the cisco, it works as expected.

Please edit the question with the show running-config command.

@RonMaupin updated as requested

If both interfaces 3 and 5 are connected via trunks to the router, then you have a problem because VLAN 99 will be tagged on both ports, but only one will work. If you really have VLAN 99 configured to use the router interface connected to switch interface 5, the you need to make sure that the router interface connected to that switch interface is tagging the traffic, otherwise you need to just make it an access interface in VLAN 99.
Really, the answer lies in how your [off-topic] router interfaces connected to the switch are configured.
